# Javascript lookup for value between upper and lower limit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working on a project in angularjs. I need help with creating a function which maps a single value to an array of json data containing range and return i.e. if value is within the range, then assign corresponding return value for that range. How can I achieve this using lookup function in javascript. An example of a json table I am using is this:

```
[{"LI":"05:0","LS":null,"points":0},
 {"LI":"04:00","LS":"05:00","points":3},
 {"LI":"03:00","LS":"4:00","points":4},
 {"LI":null,"LS":"3:00","points":4}
]
```

Basically, if value is >= 5.00 return 0, if value >= 4.00 and value < 5.00,, return 3.

The function receives json table and value to lookup, then returns the points corresponding to that interval.

Comment: Post your JavaScript function in your question.

Comment: "value is >= 5.00 return 0" what is value in this statement?

Comment: I am yet to create any function. I have done some search on using lookup functions in javascript but most examples are for cases of direct mappings. @Rupinder, example: using a prototype like FunctionName(value, jsonArray) with the array defined above, if I do FunctionName(3.5, jsonArray) the result would be 4.

Comment: We can't do the work for you, sadly. So you'll have to try something and then show us what you've tried, and then we can help you fix it. :)

Comment: @EzekielInalegwuAkoji in hopes of being helpful there are a few things that can help you. You have a list of objects. You want to iterate through them, check some values and then return something. So, start with a loop and add some if statements. If you get stuck we are here ;P.

Comment: That is exactly what I did and I think that solves the problem. Thanks @Ktilcu for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds it useful, my final code is as follows:

```js
var app = angular.module('JsonMapping', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.Model = {
   Value: 10,
   Result: 0,
   ReferenceTable: [{"LI":85,"LS":null,"points":15},{"LI":84,"LS":85,"points":14},{"LI":83,"LS":84,"points":13},{"LI":82,"LS":83,"points":12},{"LI":81,"LS":82,"points":11},{"LI":80,"LS":81,"points":10},{"LI":78,"LS":80,"points":8},{"LI":76,"LS":78,"points":6},{"LI":74,"LS":76,"points":4},{"LI":72,"LS":74,"points":2},{"LI":70,"LS":72,"points":1},{"LI":null,"LS":70,"points":0}]
  }
  
 $scope.GetPointsForValue = function() {
       var lowerLimit = 0, upperLimit = 0, points = 0.0;

   for (var i = $scope.Model.ReferenceTable.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      lowerLimit = $scope.Model.ReferenceTable[i].LI;
      upperLimit = $scope.Model.ReferenceTable[i].LS;

      if(lowerLimit === null && parseFloat($scope.Model.Value) < upperLimit) {
          $scope.Model.Result = $scope.Model.ReferenceTable[i].points;
          break;
       }else if (upperLimit === null && parseFloat($scope.Model.Value) >= lowerLimit) {
          $scope.Model.Result = $scope.Model.ReferenceTable[i].points;
          break;
       }else if (upperLimit > parseFloat($scope.Model.Value) && parseFloat($scope.Model.Value) >= lowerLimit){
          $scope.Model.Result = $scope.Model.ReferenceTable[i].points;
          break;
       }
   }
};
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="JsonMapping">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Map value to Json Array</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="Model.Value" ng-change="GetPointsForValue()">
  <p>Points for value = {{Model.Result}}
</body>

</html>
```